# ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Priority

Tags: quarkus

When starting my Quarkus app with

java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar

or with a packed Uber-jar I get :

ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Priority

But when I start from IntelliJ or with

mvn quarkus:dev

It all start well.

Complete stackTrace:

$  java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:53)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Priority
at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder$InterceptorWithPriority$1.getPriority(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:461)
at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder$InterceptorWithPriority.(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:469)
at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder$InterceptorWithPriority.(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:448)
at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder$InterceptorWithPriority.(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:441)
at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.getDefaultInterceptors(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:213)
at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig$ConfigSources.buildInterceptors(SmallRyeConfig.java:571)
at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig$ConfigSources.(SmallRyeConfig.java:516)
at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.(SmallRyeConfig.java:66)
at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.build(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:419)
at io.quarkus.runtime.generated.Config.(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Priority
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:107)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:57)
... 26 more

Comment: Hi, any chance you can show what your `pom.xml` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

My pom is so big and ugly , witch maybe is part of the problem.
But it helped to do a lot of exclutions on jakarta.annotation-api

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

And to include version 1.3.5  of jakarta.annotation-api

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It looks like some of your dependencies might be bringing in a new version of `jakarta.annotation-api` that actually contains `jakarta.annotation.Priority` instead of `javax.annotation.Priority`, which is what Quarkus uses, because it hasn't migrated to the Jakarta namespace yet. That would mean you're using a library version that's probably incompatible with Quarkus and you should consider downgrading that to a version that depends on `javax` artifacts (for now).